# How does this SQL query work?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table name - 'tab'

Schema - (a int,b int)

```
|  a  |  b  |    
|  1  |  5  |    
|  2  |  10 |    
|  3  |  15 |

select count(*) from tab where exists 

(select count(*) from tab where b=2);
```

It gave 3 as output.
[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cea1e/6)
My doubt is that, we have no value = 2 in column 'b'(sub-query) so it returns 0, which i think is equivalent to 'not-exists', so why I get 3 as output ?

Thanks.

Comment: To add to siride's answer, `where exists (select count(*) from tab where b=2)` is essentially being evaluated as `where 1` since a count will always exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the equivalent of `NOT EXISTS`. A `SELECT COUNT(*)` always returns something: a single row with the count of values given by the rest of the query. If the rest of the query would return 0 rows (no results), then the result of `SELECT COUNT(*)` is zero, which is not NULL and is not an empty result set. A single row with a single column with value 0 still exists, so the result of `EXISTS(...)` will be true.

I think what you want is:

```
select count(*) from tab where exists
(select 1 from tab where b=2);
```

In this case, if there is no row in `tab` where `b` is 2, then no results will return from the subquery and the `EXISTS` will be false.

Of course, you can easily rewrite this query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tab
 WHERE b <> 2;
```

But I assume this is actually part of something more complex.

Comment: It was a question, and they had given same query. So you saying that '0' in subquery will be treated as exists in outer query ?

Comment: @Vimal well, that is what siride said. I would dispute its 'obviousness' but I cannot dispute its veracity.

Comment: Thanks @ siride and @Strawberry for clarification :)

Comment: @Strawberry you scared me, because you made me think I had said "obviously"! Thankfully, I did not. I would agree that it's not obvious to someone who hasn't worked with the ins and outs of SQL for a decent amount of time.

Comment: @siride It was the 'most definitely' phrase.

Comment: @Strawberry: I changed it.